# how to make the status appear approve after clicking the approve button

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[Image website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0cmf.png)I want to create an approval system, where if the agree button is clicked, the agree status appears according to the admin id

my Blade code

```
    @foreach($pinjaman as $pj)
                  <div class="col-mb-5">Nama Peminjam : {{$pj->anggota->nama}}</div><br>
                  <div class="col-mb-5">Besar Pinjaman: {{$pj->besar_pinjam}}</div><br>
                    Gaji Bersih: {{$pj->gaji_bersih}}<br>
                    Keterangan: {{$pj->gaji_bersih}}<br>
                    <!-- Persetujuan: {{$pj->approve->nama}}<br> -->
                    Status Anda : 
                    @empty($pj->approve_admin)
                    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary">Belum Ada Memilih</span>
                    @endempty
                   <br>
                   <br>
                    <form method="post" action="/updates-pinjamanUser/approve{{$pj->id}}">      
                        @csrf        
                     <input type="hidden" class="form-control @error('nama') is-invalid @enderror" name="pengurus_id" value="{{Auth::user()->pengurus->id}}" id="pengurus_id">
                     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="pinjaman_id" value="{{$pj->id}}" id="pinjaman_id">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Setuju</button>
</form>
```

[Table Database Approve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRdCE.png)

My controller

```
 public function dataPinjamanDetail($id)
{
    $admin = Pengurus::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
    $approve = ApproveAdmin::all();
    $pinjaman = Pinjaman::where('id',$id)->get();
   
    return view('admin.dataPinjamanDetail',compact('pinjaman','admin','approve'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table, I presume that the `confirmed` column is your boolean identifier as to a row or id is approved or not. If this is the case, you can include the code below inside `@foreach($pinjaman as $pj)` in your blade:

```
@if ($pj->confirmed == 1)
<p>Confirmed</p>
@else
<p>Unconfirmed<p>
@endif
```